Dynamically averaging data Per ID Per Time period Alternate Version

I am looking to be able to select a User and then have the subsequent Metrics for each month and year populate in the calendar shown.
What i am measuring is the answers from Questions 1, 2, and 3 and the number of Yes answers against the total of Yes and No answers per month per User while the NAs are ignored to be counted against.  It is being calculated with a =CountIF()/SUM(CountIFS())  Statement
I have been trying to use =COUNTIF(D2:F4,"Yes")/SUM(COUNTIFS(D2:F4,{"No","Yes"})) but its no feasible to do this for ongoing data individually per user per month

In the actual data there will be several entries for the same month and year so when the formula is made it must be able to accommodate for that

Sample Data Below:



Name
Date
Policy
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3




Fernando Mullen
1/19/2023
732498
NA
NA
No


Fernando Mullen
1/25/2023
354924
Yes
Yes
Yes


Fernando Mullen
9/23/2024
669720
NA
Yes
No


Fernando Mullen
7/14/2024
602150
No
Yes
NA


Fernando Mullen
10/16/2023
644143
NA
NA
NA


Shay Gibson
4/25/2023
442807
Yes
Yes
Yes


Shay Gibson
12/4/2023
308642
NA
NA
No


Shay Gibson
12/28/2023
407548
NA
NA
NA


Shay Gibson
9/26/2023
237033
NA
NA
NA


Shay Gibson
12/19/2023
410126
NA
NA
NA


Tyler Long
4/11/2023
803544
NA
NA
No


Tyler Long
11/5/2024
399732
Yes
Yes
Yes


Tyler Long
11/11/2024
296820
NA
NA
NA


Tyler Long
3/27/2024
791065
NA
NA
NA


Wrenley Fleming
4/26/2024
463278
NA
NA
Yes


Wrenley Fleming
9/13/2024
774485
NA
NA
NA


Wrenley Fleming
9/15/2024
244185
No
Yes
NA


Wrenley Fleming
7/22/2024
506417
NA
NA
NA


Wrenley Fleming
12/26/2024
339160
NA
NA
NA




Consider index() with match()

Try using the following formula:


=LET(
     a, FILTER($D$2:$F$20,
        ($I5&J$4=TEXT($B$2:$B$20,"mmmme"))*
        ($I$2=$A$2:$A$20),""),
     IFERROR(SUM(N(a="Yes"))/SUM(N(a<>"NA")),0))


Alternatively, can use one single array formula to return the output for the whole array..
=LET(
     _Month, I5:I16,
     _Year, J4:K4,
     _Date, TEXT(B2:B20,"mmmme"),
     _Name, A2:A20,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Month),COLUMNS(_Year),LAMBDA(x,y,
     LET(z, FILTER(D2:F20,(_Date=INDEX(_Month&_Year,x,y))*(_Name=I2),""),
     IFERROR(SUM(N(z="Yes"))/SUM(N(z<>"NA")),0)))))



What is this "mmmme" ?

@Mo-L it converts the dates to monthyear since you have the months and year as conditions

I used the first formula, not the array, but it looks like there is a separate problem with this I did not anticipate, i need if there are ONLY NA's available for it to look through for it not to calculate to zero but to N/A. It should only calculate to zero if it went through at least one yes/No

@Mo-L so you meant to say for the month of Jan in the year 2023, for Fernando Mullen it will be 0.5 instead of 0.75? is that so? But again you are saying to ignore the NAs

No, it would be .75. However, if it had been only NA's in Jan it should result in NA and not 0

@Mo-L in the IFERROR() part change the 0 to NA.

I'll try this out, it looks like it is correcting my issue in the sample data

Another issue is arising now, if there is NO DATA for any given month it is reading as 0, if there is no data for a month we would like it to also read as "NA"

@Mo-L I have already replied in your other posts. So that no confusion arises.

That was to address NAs, but i'm referring to having no data AT ALL for a given month

Try: =LET(a, FILTER($D$2:$F$20,($I5&J$4=TEXT($B$2:$B$20,"mmmme"))*($I$2=$A$2:$A$20),""),b,IF(a=0,"NA",a),IFERROR(SUM(N(b="Yes"))/SUM(N(b<>"NA")),"NA"))

i copied and pasted this into the sample, it didn't work even there. Not all users have data for all months, so the months they dont have any data it should either also say "NA" like it does for months listed but have no Yes/No answers or just say "No Data" but, it should not calculate to 0%

Do you have the excel? can you post the link using google sheet link? in the comments below. Because it is working on my end

I hope this works. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rAfp_hUPyn8rrM3TnrDF4VLtkFhNDSumUI3mKpICz_s/edit?usp=sharing

Here: Check

It looks like you added the "c, IFERROR(SUM(N(b="Yes"))/SUM(N(b<>"NA")),"NA"),
IF(c=0,"NA",c))... from this everything seems correct, thank you. Let me sit on it for a few days with the real data to confirm nothing else arises

@Mo-L sure please take time.

Dynamic Averaging
=LET(sn,Table1[Name],sd,Table1[Date],sq,Table1[[Q1]:[Q3]],
        dn,I2,dy,J4:K4,y,"Yes",n,"No",ina,"",
    sm,YEAR(sd)&MONTH(sd),
    dm,dy&SEQUENCE(12),
    MAKEARRAY(ROWS(dm),COLUMNS(dm),LAMBDA(r,c,LET(
        f,FILTER(sq,(sm=INDEX(dm,r,c))*(sn=dn)),
        yc,SUM(N(f=y)),
        tc,SUM(N(f=n))+yc,
        IFERROR(yc/tc,ina)))))



This was not Plug and play for me, did you change some things? Looks like you made this into a table? The data will be populated ongoing increasing in volume month to month, does that mean every time we have a data dump we have to reformat the table?

It's as simple as the following: create a copy of your workbook. Select a cell in the left table and press Ctrl+T to convert the range to a table. Then copy my formula to cell J2 and see what happens. Don't forget to change the headers for quanitity either in the formula or the table. Then add more data and see if the formula recognizes the change. I mean, using a structured table for the source data is the only way to make it efficient and fully dynamic.
